# JSF - What happens if value EL expression evaluates to null?

Tags: jsf, datatable, null, footer

What will happen if the EL expression like #{bean.list} is null. I've a nested datatable and the "value" of dataTable evaluates to null. In below example if issuerList is null, outer table footer is displayed but not the inner table. How does #{Issuer.issue} is handled considering "Issuer" is null !!!

Ex:

```
    <h:datatable value="#{bean.issuerList}" var="issuer" >
         ..  
      <h:datatable value="#{issuer.issueList}" var="issue" >
         ....
         ....
         <f:facet name="footer">
             This is inner footer
         </f:facet>
      </h:datatable>  
     <f:facet name="footer" >
          This is outer footer
     </f:facet>  
</h:datatable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `#{bean.issuerList}` is `null` then there are simply no rows to render. Since the nested datatable (and its footer) is part of a row, it's also never rendered. You would need at least one row to get the nested datatable (and its footer) to render. The footer of the outer datatable is not part of any row, so it's always rendered.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. So, does that mean, footer though attached to datatable is not dependent on "data" of datatable. Its rendered irrespective of data is present or not (as in case of outer footer). What is the best source to understand rendering of datatable ?

Comment: The footer is only rendered if the datatable itself is also rendered. The outer datatable is always rendered as it doesn't have a `rendered="#{not empty bean.issuerList}"` attribute. But when the outer datatable doesn't contain any rows, then the inner datatable is never rendered. So its footer is also never rendered. If you want to hide the outer datatable's footer as well, then simply add `rendered="#{not empty bean.issuerList}"` to the outer datatable.